# Bash expand array whose name is contained in a function parameter

Tags: bash

I would like to render this code more natural:

```
#!/bin/bash

 declare -ra dev_monikers=(foo bar baz)
 declare -ra starwars_expletives=(farkled kark crink)

 function f() {
   local -r weird_expansion="$1[@]"
   local -ra words_to_use=(${!weird_expansion})
   echo "${words_to_use[@]}"
 }

 f dev_monikers
 echo ---
 f starwars_expletives
```

Specifically: it seems very odd indeed to use that `weird_expansion` auxiliary variable. Is there a simpler way to do this in Bash?

Output from the above:

```
foo bar baz
---
farkled kark crink
```

Things I have tried which do *not* work:

```
words_to_use=(${${1}[@]}) # error
words_to_use=(${$1[@]}) # error
words_to_use=(${!$1[@]}) # error
words_to_use=(${!1[@]}) # error
words_to_use=(${!${1}[@]}) # error
words_to_use=(${${!1}[@]} # error
```

Making, in comparison, the initial absurdity look less unreasonable..

Comment: Long story short, no. That's the very best Bash-only non-eval non-nameref method. It's actually only marginally better than `eval`. Always use quotes in a compound assignment. `x=("${!y}")`. If you wanted to make this portable then things get quite a lot harder still. `${${...` is never valid unless you're generating a PE through `eval` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function f() {
    eval "echo \${$1[@]}"
}
```

Comment: `eval` is "exciting": `f '1}; $(mkdir /tmp/a_new_virus_found_a_home)'` :( - does not happen with the other function..

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily any more pretty, but does it without the auxiliary variable:

```
function f() {
    local -a words_to_use=($(eval echo \$\{${1}[@]\}))
    echo ${words_to_use[@]}
}
```

Comment: Agreed, I would be wary of it too, unless you-the-script-writer has complete control over what gets passed to the function.